# Extend conditions in a dynamic way

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I am trying to build a decision table. At time 3 for example I have to take the previous results in time t=1 and time t=2 in order to make my decision in time 3. The decision table is going to be pretty big so I am considering an efficient way to do it by building a function. For instance at time 3:

```
rm(list=ls())   # clear memory
names <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k50","l50","m50","n50","o50")

proba <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)
need <- 4
re <- 0.5
w <- 1000000000

  # t1
  t1 <- as.integer(names %in% (sample(names,need,prob=proba,replace=F)))

  # t2
  t2 <- rep(t1)

  # t3
  proba3 <- ifelse(t2==1,proba*re,proba)
  t3 <- as.integer(names %in% (sample(names,need,prob=proba3,replace=F)))
```

Now the table is going to be big until t=7 with proba7 which takes condition from t=1 to t=6. After t=7 it always takes the 6 previous outcomes plus the random part proba in order to make decision. In other words the ifelse must be dynamic in order that I can call it later. I have been trying something like

```
probF <- function(a){
  test <- ifelse(paste0("t",a,sep="")==1,proba*re,proba)
  return(test)
}

test <- probF(2)
```

but there is an error as I got just one value and not a vector. I know that it looks complicated

For the conditions requested by one person (i know it's not very good written) :

```
proba7 <- ifelse(t2==1 & t3==1 & t4==0 & t5==0 & t6==0,proba,
                 ifelse(t2==1 & t3==0 & t4==0 & t5==1 & t6==1,proba*re,
                        ifelse(t2==1 & t3==0 & t4==0 & t5==0 & t6==1, w,
                               ifelse(t2==0 & t3==1 & t4==1 & t5==0 & t6==0,proba,
                                      ifelse(t2==0 & t3==1 & t4==1 & t5==1 & t6==0,0,
                                             ifelse(t2==0 & t3==0 & t4==1 & t5==1 & t6==1,0,
                                                    ifelse(t2==0 & t3==0 & t4==1 & t5==1 &t6==0,0,
                                                           ifelse(t2==0 & t3==0 & t4==0 & t5==1 & t6==1, proba*re,
                                                                  ifelse(t2==0 & t3==0 & t4==0 & t5==0 & t6==1,w,proba)))))))))

t7 <- as.integer(names %in% (sample(names,need,prob=proba7,replace=F)))
```

Comment: Sounds an awful approach to the problem, hence this question seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I am trying to make a decision table. However the decision in time t takes the previous decision from t-6 to t-1 as given plus a random effect. But youre right my question is not very clear I am going to update it

Comment: @Tensibai I edited all my question in order to make it clearer, does it help?

Comment: Yes, a little more clear what's expected, looking at your previous version, the decision tree sounds strange, as there's 3 way to get `proba`, significant entries are only t4 and t6 ..

Comment: youre complety right, I just wrote everything in order not to be confused

Comment: I assume you're just missing a call to `get` to get the variable by it's name as character: i.e: `ifelse( get( paste0("t",a) ),...`

Comment: @Tensibai thank you very much that's exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the quality of my question and thanks also for your patience. have a nice day

Comment: there's a lot of optimization possible. What exactly is the condition? t6 equal to t1 - t5, or any of t1 to t6 equal to any other of t1 to t6?

Comment: to let you know the conditions are: but as Tenisbai suggested they are not very optimal so I am working on ii (i put them in my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a bit of a different approach, you'll gain quite a lot of speed.

First of all, it is really a terribly bad idea to store every step as a separate t1, proba1, etc. If you need to keep all that information, predefine a matrix or list of the right size and store everything in there. That way you can use simple indices instead of having to resort to the bug-prone use of `get()`. If you find yourself typing `get()`, almost always it's time to stop and rethink your solution.

Secondly, you can use a simple principle to select the indices of the test t:

```
seq(max(0, i-7), i-1)
```

will allow you to use a loop index `i` and refer to the 6 previous positions if they exist.

Thirdly, depending on what you want, you can reformulate your decision as well. If you store every t as a row in the matrix, you can simply use `colSums()` and check whether that one is larger than 0. Based on that index, you can update the probabilities in such a way that a 1 in any of the previous 6 rows halfs the probability.

wrapping everything in a function would then look like :

```
myfun <- function(names, proba, need, re,
                  w=100){

  # For convenience, so I don't have to type this twice
  resample <- function(p){
    as.integer(
      names %in% sample(names,need,prob=p, replace = FALSE)
    )
  } 
  # get the number of needed columns
  nnames <- length(names)

  # create two matrices to store all the t-steps and the probabilities used
  theT <- matrix(nrow = w, ncol = nnames)
  theproba <- matrix(nrow = w, ncol = nnames)

  # Create a first step, using the original probabilities
  theT[1,] <- resample(proba)
  theproba[1,] <- proba

  # loop over the other simulations, each time checking the condition
  # recalculating the probability and storing the result in the next
  # row of the matrices

  for(i in 2:w){

    # the id vector to select the (maximal) 6 previous rows. If 
    # i-6 is smaller than 1 (i.e. there are no 6 steps yet), the
    # max(1, i-6) guarantees that you start minimal at 1.
    tid <- seq(max(1, i-6), i-1)

    # Create the probability vector from the original one
    p <- proba
    # look for which columns in the 6 previous steps contain a 1
    pid <- colSums(theT[tid,,drop = FALSE]) > 0
    # update the probability vector
    p[pid] <- p[pid]*0.5

    # store the next step and the used probabilities in the matrices
    theT[i,] <- resample(p)
    theproba[i,] <- p

  }

  # Return both matrices in a single list for convenience
  return(list(decisions = theT,
              proba = theproba)
  )
}
```

which can be used as:

```
myres <- myfun(names, proba, need, re, w)
head(myres$decisions)
head(myres$proba)
```

This returns you a matrix where every row is one t-point in the decision table.

Comment: @ Joris Meys Wow this is great, I will have alook carefully in order to understand it but please give me some time as i am a new user with R. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @branchwarren I might have misread your condition. I've updated my answer so it now checks which name has been selected in any of the 6 previous steps. If you need more explanation, shoot.

Comment: @ Joris Meys: I put the conditions above (in the question if it helps)

Comment: @branchwarren I've updated my answer (I was actually looking at the previous 7 steps instead of 6). I also added a bit of explanation on what I am doing. The most important thing for you, is to look at how I use matrices here instead of all different objects. All that paste() and get() will also make your code very, very slow. 

The description of the conditions is a bit awkward. What my code does now, is check whether a name has been chosen any time in the previous 6 steps. If so, probability for that name is multiplied by 0.5

Comment: @branchwarren The thing you should do, is replace the 3 lines that construct `p` with something that constructs the probabilities you want. Keep in mind you have a trick for selecting previous rows without running into trouble (using max()), and a matrix where every step t has its own line. So this should get you on the way.

Comment: @ Joris Meys First of all, simply thank you. This website is great because there are a lot of people like you helping others who have difficulties. I will have a close look tonight and I will arrange my code for my purpose. Thanks again and all the best

Comment: @ Joris Meys I have a question because your code is very nice written. However I cannot implement the conditions I need (cf question) with colSums, do you have a trick or something? thanks again for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104253/discussion-between-joris-meys-and-branchwarren).